# Alter a single attribute with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

What's the simplest **XSLT** you can think of to transform the value of the first, in this case only, `/configuration/system.web/compilation/@debug` attribute from `true` to `false`?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short, simple and correct solution. Lucero's answer at present is quite incorrect --see my comment to his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="system.web/compilation[1]/@debug">
  <xsl:attribute name="debug">false</xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document:**

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="C#">
            <!-- this is a comment -->
        </compilation>

        <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="C#">
            <!-- this is another comment -->
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:** modifies the `debug` attribute of the first `compilation` child of any `system.web` element (but we know that there is only one `system.web` element in a config file.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" defaultLanguage="C#">
            <!-- this is a comment -->
        </compilation>
        <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="C#">
            <!-- this is another comment -->
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

As we see, only the first `debug` atribute is modifird to `false`, as required.

Comment: This is called the identity pattern transform for XSLT, and as @Dimitre Novatchev pointed out, it's extremely powerful.

Comment: It's a shame that the `xsl:attribute` element has to mention the name of the attribute to be changed, when that has already been given in the XPath that the enclosing `xsl:template` matches. Is there any way to say "set this attribute, whatever it's called"?

Comment: @TomAnderson: One can use the AVT notation: `<someElement attr1="{someExpression}"/>`  This isn't what you want but in some respect is even better.

Comment: You mean in combination with a match on the element which has the attribute? Then you have the (even worse, i think) problem that you need to manually duplicate all the attributes you don't want to keep.

Comment: @TomAnderson: But you are "in full control". So, again about your original question: no, this is a too-composite operation and it the language had single instructions to represent all possible composite operations, it would be huge and unwieldy.

Answer (score -1):

`<xsl:attribute name="debug">false</xsl:attribute>` inside the `<compilation>`? Or am I misunderstanding the question?